# Cable pull, indexing of Shimano's IGH vs. deraileur

Tags: derailleur-rear, internally-geared-hub, cable-routing

What's the exact cable pull and indexing of

- Shimano Alfine SG-S700
- SRAM G8/9
- Shimano ROAD RD-5800
- SRAM Force Rear dérailleur
- other...

The idea is to use ST-RS505 brifter with an IGH. Not entirely impossible [as it seems](http://blog.artscyclery.com/science-behind-the-magic/science-behind-the-magic-drivetrain-compatibility/).

Comment: The blog article that you reference is specific to external, derailleur gears. IGHs are engineered to use specific pull ratios that correspond only with IGH shifters.

Comment: @JonR The title is explicitly asking for specific values. Not opinions.

There is [another fact sheet](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/cribsheet-IG-cable-pull.html) suggesting otherwise. I haven't had the time to integrate the details, yet.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you may read this CAN'T work properly simply because the gaps between each of the shifts are different on the Shimano Alfine SG-S700, there are THREE different gaps. The only shifters not made by Shimano to operate this hub properly are:

[Jtek 11 Speed Bar End Shifter](http://www.sjscycles.co.uk/jtek-11-speed-bar-end-shifter-for-shimano-alfine-sg-s700-internal-hub-prod38738/)

and:

[11 Speed Microshift Inter11 STI Levers](http://www.sjscycles.co.uk/11-speed-microshift-inter11-sti-levers-for-shimano-internal-gear-hubs-prod39799/)